# Syntax Error in Java (JavaFX)

Tags: java, syntax

I realize this might not be the most unique question but I've been trying to figure out the syntax problem with this program and haven't been able to figure it out. Here's where I'm getting the syntax error:

```
});    
            catch
```

Here's the code:

```
public class MySQLGUI extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField field = new TextField();
        field.setPrefWidth(420);
        TextField order = new TextField();
        order.setPrefWidth(420);
        TextField where = new TextField();
        where.setPrefWidth(420);
        Button button = new Button("Retrieve Records");
        TextArea table = new TextArea();
        table.setEditable(false);


        HBox tfield = new HBox();
        tfield.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Fields:"),field);
        tfield.setSpacing(10);
        HBox torder = new HBox();
        torder.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Order:"),order);
        torder.setSpacing(10);
        HBox twhere = new HBox();
        twhere.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Where:"),where);
        twhere.setSpacing(7);
        VBox top = new VBox();
        top.setSpacing(10);
        top.getChildren().addAll(tfield,torder,twhere,button);
        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(top,table);

        // Set scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 480, 313);
        primaryStage.setTitle("MySQLGUI"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage   
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pcparts", "root", "password");
            System.out.println("Database connected");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot connect");
        }
        try {
            java.sql.Statement st = conn.createStatement();

            String query = "select " + field.getText();
            query += " from customers";
            query += " where " + where.getText();
            query += " order by " + order.getText();
            button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    java.sql.ResultSet rSet = st.executeQuery(query);
                    while (rSet.next())  {
                        table.setText(rSet.getString(1) + " " + rSet.getString(2) + " " + rSet.getString(3) + " " + rSet.getString(4) + " " + rSet.getString(5) + " " + rSet.getString(6));
                    }
                }
            }
        });    
        catch (SQLException ex) {
        // handle the error 
        table.setText("OOPS...");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The parenthesis is closing the .setOnAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed the ); one curly bracket too late. The part of your code should be:

```
try
{
    /*Your code*/
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        /*More code*/
    });
}
catch(SQLException ex)
{
    /*Even more code*/
}
```

It was just a minor mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax for try catch statements is:

```
try {
    tryStatements
}
catch(exception){catchStatements
}
finally {
    finallyStatements
}
```